# Android mini game - Delay the code

Tags: java, android, delay, handler

First time programming in android studio and are trying to make a minimum viable product of the cognitive test Digit Span. The idea is that you are shown a number every X second and when all the numbers have been shown, you need to type the right numbers in the order they appeared. If you are right, the amount of numbers increase for the next run.

The problem I'm encountering is with the delay I wanna impose on the numbers popping up. I've tried using handlers, but to no succes and are running out of ideas.

Here's a small handmade example of a code that isn't working as intended:

```
 handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(counter < difficulty) {
                        numberText.setText(numbersArray.get(counter) + "");
                        counter += 1;
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 600);
                    }else{
                        handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    }
                }
            });
```

The problem is that the rest of the code keeps running while the handler is delayed. What I want is for the entire code to be delayed by X seconds before continuing.
  Another problem with handlers are that you can't acces variables that aren't final outside the handler, so counters aren't working for me.

Hope it's just me being an idiot and that there's a simple solution to my problem.

Edit: While I'm here, is it possible to have a delay inside another delay? Just so I know in the future.

Comment: you can always make variables Global and call methods from inside your Handlers

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the rest of the code keeps running while the handler is delayed

Move all code you want to be delayed to a method and call that method from the runner according to your requirements.

> Another problem with handlers are that you can't acces variables that aren't final outside the handler, so counters aren't working for me.

You can define the counter variable as global class field, then you can access it from anywhere inside your class without declaring it as final variable.